# on hover effect next menu item hide behind current menu OR shrink all items on horizontal navbar

Tags: css

on hover effect next menu item hide behind current menu OR shrink all items on horizontal navbar

----------------------------css-----------------------------------

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
    text-align: left;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x 0px 30px;
}
.dsply { display: none; }

.logo { background: url(../images/logo.jpg) no-repeat 25px 25px; 
        float:left;     
        width: 175px; 
        height: 150px;
}   
.nav-flag-left { 
        float:left; 
        margin-top:47px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width: 13px; 
        height: 40px;
} 
#menu { 
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top:47px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;     
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #DA9AFB; 
    background-color:#F6F9E8; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#menu li {
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:auto;
}   
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#7D169D;
    padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li:hover {
    display:inline;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #FCF;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-image: url(../images/pinkcloud.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
    top:40px;
    height:60px;
    width:90px;
    position:absolute; 
}
.nav-flag-plane {  
        float:left; 
        margin-top:32px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width: 109px; 
        height: 71px;
} 

.nav-menu-cloude {  
        float:left; 
        margin-top:32px;
        margin-left:35px;
        width: 109px; 
        height: 75px;
}
```

------------------------html-------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Baby Zone</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="logo"><a href="index.html" title="Baby Zone"><span class="dsply">Baby Zone</span></a> </div>
<div class="nav-flag-left"><img src="images/nav-flag-left.png" width="13" height="40" /></div>
<div id="menu">

<ul>

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="brands.html">Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-flag-plane"><img src="images/plane.png" width="109" height="71" /></div>
<div class="nav-menu-cloude"><img src="images/menucload.png" width="109" height="75" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change position to absolute on hover? this is why is breaking your menu

```
position:absolute;
```

So your class should be:

```
#menu li:hover {
    display:inline;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #FCF;
    padding-top:20px;
/*  background-color:#7D169D;*/
    background-image: url(../images/pinkcloud.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
/*  background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 60px 90px; */
    top:40px;
    height:60px;
    width:90px;
}
```

You can see it working on: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZQH3/

Comment: thanx its working without changing position but the hover image not showing properly with out changing position.

Comment: You put both images in same file, and just change background-position on hover. This is a wide-used technique to make this hover effect that you want. You can check a tutorial here: http://return-true.com/2010/04/making-a-css-image-rollover-using-background-positionmaking-a-css-image-rollover-using-background-position/